# List with icon displayed in a single row instead of multiple rows

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a normal list with icon classes like below

```
<div class="dropdown search">
<div class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Search
<span class="caret"></span></div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="icon-mobile" ng-click="changeAssetDetails('SmartPhone')"></li>
<li class="icon-tablet" ng-click="changeAssetDetails('Tablets')"></li>
<li class="icon-cogs" ng-click="changeAssetDetails('Solution')"></li>
<li class="icon-file-spreadsheet2 text-orange-800 " ng-click="changeAssetDetails('SimCard')"></li>
```

I expect each list items should appear in a row as normal behavior. But I am getting all items in a single line. I have uploaded an image for the same below 
[image]

Can some one help me to resolve this issue ??

My expected result will be each icons will be displayed in each line.

Note : Below is the css from browser inspect element window

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your css?

Comment: post your css please

Comment: @sconner87 css for icons??

Comment: dropdown-menu css please :)

Comment: The CSS for that ul as well as the li.

Comment: Remove inline-block and you should be good to go. You might also need list-style-type:none;

Comment: @Highdef cool sure i will do that

Comment: @Highdef you can post it as an answer

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As mentioned in my comment you need to make the following changes:**

- Remove `display:inline-block` (Removes the inline styling property making li retain their default row aligned behaviour)
- Add `list-style-type:none` (To hide the default bullets of li)

```css
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1em;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown search">
<div class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Search
<span class="caret"></span></div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="icon-mobile" ng-click="changeAssetDetails('SmartPhone')">D</li>
<li class="icon-tablet" ng-click="changeAssetDetails('Tablets')">A</li>
<li class="icon-cogs" ng-click="changeAssetDetails('Solution')">B</li>
<li class="icon-file-spreadsheet2 text-orange-800 " ng-click="changeAssetDetails('SimCard')">C</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this css**

```
        .dropdown-menu li {
           display:inline-block;
         }
```

Comment: it is not working , working when i choose display :inherit

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say without possibility to inspect element full CSS file but it should help:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Don't post solutions based on assumptions and wait till the OP adds the CSS style code.